# Flutter show icon overlap with column

Tags: flutter

I need to show the avatar and a column in a row which look like overlapping each other.
Something like this

[image]

I have done with the left side but don't know how can I add this type of icon which seems like overlapping with my column here is my code

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Color(0xff1b4881),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: height * 0.05,
                  ),
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: new SizedBox(
                          child: FloatingActionButton(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Color(0xff1b4881),),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                      ))),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: height * 0.03,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    width: width * 0.7,
                    height: height * 0.1,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'Rtn.XYZZ',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'President',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20, right: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('AskNilesh'),
                      Text('AskNilesh'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  right: 0,
                  top: 0,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0))),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can the Stack Widget to overlap widgets:

```
Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Rtn.xxx'),
                  Text('secretory'),
                ],
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 10,
                right: 10,
                top: 10,
                bottom: 10,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  child: Image.asset('blablabla.png'),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
```

then play with values of top, left, right, button in the Positioned widget to align the item exactly as you want it.